# GORM many-to-many on same domain

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I want to create a relation many-to-many between the same entity.

```
class Device {
    static hasMany = [devices: Device]
}
```

But that leaves me with just one-to-many. How can I accomplish this?
I know there are quite a few examples of many-to-many between two domains or many-to-many when there is a link to two sets of same domain in different one, but I can't find such example nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a sort of hacked many to many with another list of Devices

```
class Device {

    static hasMany = [devicesOwnedBy: Device, devicesOwned: Device]

}
```

Here you have a Device - devices 1..* and Device - devicesOwned 1..*

I doubt this is the solution you are looking for, but it might suffice till another answer comes along.